Loading a package once in several @examples section of R package
I'm loading STExampleData several times in several examples of my package.
I do that in order to retrieve an input for my example but it can be slow.
@examples 
library(STexampleData)
spe <- Visium_humanDLPFC() # this is the bottleneck
see ?STexampleData and browseVignettes('STexampleData') for documentation loading from cache
#do_stuff(spe)

This pacakge is defined in Suggests because i'm only use it in examples.
I was wondering if I could do something to load it once to decrease run times of these examples where it load each time.

I would seriously consider providing my own example dataset in the package.
